# What's the meaning of "bounced right back"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

This is a passage from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> *"It's those C-sections,"* Georgie's mom would say. As if Georgie had chosen to have two C-sections, as if she'd order them off the menu out of sheer laziness *"I had you girls the natural way, and **my body bounced right back**."*

What does it mean when she said her body bounced right back? Does it mean she become slim again right away after giving birth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something *bouncing right back* means something returning to normal very quickly.

It is often used to refer to health returning to normal.

In the quote you gave, *my body bounced right back* means the mother's body returned to normal soon after giving birth.

Answer (score 5):

To *bounce back* is used idiomatically to mean to return to a good, successful or healthy state after a problem. In this case it means to return to a good state of health. Depending on the context this could also involve being slim and good looking.

The preposition *back* nearly always indicates returning to a previous state or previous location. This can help you guess the meaning of [verb] plus [*back*] combinations.

The word *right* is a specialised word (most grammars think it is an adverb). It is often used to modify prepositions. It can have several meanings. It can mean *immediately*, *completely*, *directly* or *exactly*. This adverb cannot be used to modify adjectives or adverbs in standard English.

In the Original Poster's example the word *right* in the phrase *bounced right back* means that her  body recovered quickly and without any problems. It also indicates a sense of completeness indicating that her body was just as healthy as it was before she had the children.

Another specialised adverb for modifying prepositions is the adverb *straight*. It has a similar meaning to *right*:

- It went straight past me.
- It went right past me.